# Apache mod_rewrite for aaa.bbb.ccc.com to aaa.org

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write my mod_rewrite rules in my .htaccess file to fix the URL that shows up in the browser bar when visitors to to my site. I have a few options that I want my users to be able to enter. They should be able to enter something like:

```
aaa.xxx.yyy.edu
bbb.xxx.yyy.edu
```

and it should forward to

```
bbb.org
```

where bbb.org is a URL that I own that's pointing to the site now. I've already got a rule that removes www. from the front of either of those, and I have a rule that will forward aaa.xxx.yyy.edu to bbb.xxx.yyy.edu, but if you go to bbb.org, the URL in the browser bar shows up as bbb.xxx.yyy.edu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(aaa|bbb)\.xxx\.yyy\.edu$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bbb.org$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Redirect instead:

Redirect Permanent / http://bbb.org/

Put this inside a vhost that responds to both the hostnames:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
 ServerName aaa.xxx.yyy.edu
 ServerAlias bbb.xxx.yyy.edu
 Redirect Permanent / http://bbb.org/
</Virtualhost>
```